# Arduino Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, avr

```
:10 00D0 00 B207 E1F7 0E94 BA00 0C94 6801 0C94 0000 8A
:10 00D0 00 B207 E1F7 0E94 BA00 0C94 6901 0C94 0000 89
```

I need some help in understanding the hex file generated for ATMega328p. I wrote a program in Arduino which turns LED 1 on (it is connected to pin ... of the microcontroller. ) Then I wrote another program which does just the opposite - it turns the same LED off.

Now when I compare the hex files for the two programs, the difference is seen in the two lines shown above, and the exact difference is that the program that turns the LED on has an instruction 6801 and the one that turns the LED off has the instruction 6901 at the same location.

I want to know what instructions these 6801 and 6901 represent. I tried to find the instruction set for ATmega328p but couldn't find one. The only document I was able to see is "Atmel 856 instruction set". According to this document, any instruction that starts with 6 is ORI/SBR which is basically ORing a register with an immediate value. But in case of turning the LED off, something should be ANDed. So I'm totally lost. Can anyone help me out in this? Thanks.

```
Difference found on line 14:
File 1: :1000D000B207E1F70E94BA000C9469010C94000089
File 2: :1000D000B207E1F70E94BA000C9468010C9400008A
Difference found on line 38:
File 1: :100250002223C1F0882339F0833021F1C8F48130A2
File 2: :100250002223B9F0882339F0833019F1C0F48130BA
Difference found on line 39:
File 1: :1002600039F1823049F1E22FF0E0EE0FFF1FEE5836
File 2: :1002600031F1823041F1E22FF0E0EE0FFF1FEE5846
Difference found on line 40:
File 1: :10027000FF4FA591B4918FB7F8942C91909592234C
File 2: :10027000FF4FA591B4918FB7F8942C91922B9C933A
Difference found on line 41:
File 1: :100280009C938FBFC114D104E9F20E940000DACF21
File 2: :100280008FBFC114D104F1F20E940000DBCF873090
Difference found on line 42:
File 1: :100290008730A9F08830C9F0843029F78091800038
File 2: :10029000A9F08830C9F0843031F7809180008F7DDB
Difference found on line 43:
File 1: :1002A0008F7D03C0809180008F7780938000DBCFAB
File 2: :1002A00003C0809180008F7780938000DCCF84B57D
Difference found on line 44:
File 1: :1002B00084B58F7784BDD7CF84B58F7DFBCF8091F8
File 2: :1002B0008F7784BDD8CF84B58F7DFBCF8091B00080
Difference found on line 45:
File 1: :1002C000B0008F778093B000CECF8091B0008F7D4B
File 2: :1002C0008F778093B000CFCF8091B0008F7DF9CF32
Difference found on line 46:
File 1: :0602D000F9CFF894FFCF06
File 2: :0402D000F894FFCFD0
```

Comment: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf

Comment: Please do not post another question on the same issue, instead edit your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75711605/11294831) and, if done well, it will be re-opened.

Comment: The common process is to disassemble the hex files and to compare these listings. Did you try this? -- Depending on your build process, you can already generate the listing upfront. -- Since your hex files are not _that_ long, you can even post them here completely. Then someone can show you how to do the disassembly.

Comment: The difference is apparently in the later parts of the binary. -- You mention that you looked into the instruction set and found the respective opcode, but you lack to show us the complete disassembly.

Comment: Firstly - AVR use low endian format, so opcode is 0x0168 and 0x0169.
Secondly - please provide source of your code. If you are use arduino functions as `digitalWrite` then you can't find in code instruction like OR and AND, because you only setup some parameters for this function.
Thirdly as I write comment to your first post use disassembler if you want see difference on instruction level.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions on how to solve this problem.

### 1. Reading the Instruction Set Manual

This is not very practical because you'll have to real all the manual until you find the opcode. Ayway, a copy of the instruction manual is [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf).

### 2. Disassemble a small Sample Program

The opcode is 0x6801 or 0x0168 for the first line, depending on the endianness in which the values of the dump are represented. So we disassemble, say

```cpp
int main (void)
{
    asm volatile (".word 0x6801");
    asm volatile (".word 0x6901");
    asm volatile (".word 0x0168");
    asm volatile (".word 0x0169");
}
```

using, say

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p -Os foo.c -o foo.elf && avr-objdump -d foo.elf
```

which outputs (irrelevant insns removed):

```
00000000 <main>:
   0:   01 68           ori r16, 0x81
   2:   01 69           ori r16, 0x91
   4:   68 01           movw    r12, r16
   6:   69 01           movw    r12, r18
   ...
```

so it's either `ori` or `movw`.

### 3. Disassemble the IntelHex File

You can disassemble that iHex file by beans of, say

`avr-objdump -m avr5 -D foo.hex`

Then you can use your preferred diff tool like `diff` or `kdiff3` to display the differences between the two disassemblies.

### 4. Let the GNU Assembler print Disassembly of the Object File(s)

Theres actually no need to go through iHex when you have the source code and thus the object code available.  So advise the GNU assembler to dump the object doce is its assembling, say

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p -Os foo.c -c -g2 -Wa,-alhs
```

This will print asm intermingled with C/C++ source code.  For the mini example with inline asm from above:

```
   1:foo.c         **** int main (void)
   2:foo.c         **** {
...
   3:foo.c         ****     asm volatile (".word 0x6801":);
  22                    .loc 1 3 5 view .LVU1
  23                /* #APP */
  24                 ;  3 "foo.c" 1
  25 0000 0168              .word 0x6801
  26                 ;  0 "" 2
   4:foo.c         ****     asm volatile (".word 0x6901":);
  27                    .loc 1 4 5 view .LVU2
  28                 ;  4 "foo.c" 1
  29 0002 0169              .word 0x6901
  30                 ;  0 "" 2
   5:foo.c         ****     asm volatile (".word 0x0168":);
  31                    .loc 1 5 5 view .LVU3
  32                 ;  5 "foo.c" 1
  33 0004 6801              .word 0x0168
  34                 ;  0 "" 2
   6:foo.c         ****     asm volatile (".word 0x0169":);
  35                    .loc 1 6 5 view .LVU4
  36                 ;  6 "foo.c" 1
  37 0006 6901              .word 0x0169
  38                 ;  0 "" 2
   7:foo.c         **** }
```